# Kurento Media Server recording without Audio not working

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, kurento, mediastream

I tried out the following demo for Kurento Media Server:

https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js/tree/master/kurento-recorder

The default demo worked well. But, when I changed the `index.js` to record with `audio: false`, I start to face problems.

I have only made the following change in the `index.js` code:

```
var mediaConstraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: {
    width: 320,
    framerate: 15
  }   
};

var options = {
  localVideo: videoInput,
  remoteVideo: videoOutput,
  mediaConstraints: mediaConstraints      
};
```

If I run the code with `audio: true`, recording file created on the server is correct.

However, with `audio: false`, recording file is always `0KB` in size.

I don't see anything special in the logs. The only error log that comes is while pressing the "STOP" button. It behaves like STOP button was already pressed, even though it wasn't.

Detailed Logs are put here: https://pastebin.com/397U14uG

I am sure some stream is coming to the server since my server does show data transfer with the `ifstat` command.

**Kurento Version**

```
root@ip-10-0-0-49:/var/log/kurento-media-server# kurento-media-server -v
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
Version: 6.6.2
Found modules:
        Module: 'core' version '6.6.3'
        Module: 'elements' version '6.6.3'
        Module: 'filters' version '6.6.2'
```

**Ubuntu Version**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Answer (score 3):

The recorderEndpoint object has a mediaProfile attribute denoting which kind of data it's waiting to record. By default it'll be WEBM audio and video. When your media constraints remove the audio coming from the client it'll make the recorderEndpoint wait for an audio stream to start recording, and since it'll never come the file will stay at 0kb. The correct way to deal with this is to modify the creation of the recorder endpoint in [line 112](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js/blob/master/kurento-recorder/js/index.js#L112) to something like this:

```
{type: 'RecorderEndpoint', params: {uri : args.file_uri, mediaProfile: 'WEBM_VIDEO_ONLY'}},
```

For reference:

- [Recorder Endpoint](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/client-jsdoc/module-elements.RecorderEndpoint.html)
- [mediaProfile values](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/client-jsdoc/node_modules_kurento-client-elements_lib_complexTypes_MediaProfileSpecType.js.html)

Comment: Thanks. I got this to work already, by using the JAVA example:
https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/tree/master/kurento-hello-world-recording

Comment: Will you be able to solve this problem as well? 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/_KYkcWpVtb4

Comment: As far as I know you cant record audio as wav without modifications to the kurento media server source code